# Deploying a Java application on Play Framework 1.2 on Heroku, how can I ensure it can handle higher loads?

Tags: mysql, deployment, heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have signed-up on Heroku for Free, now I am trying to deploy my Play Framework 1.2 Java application on it. Can I add a webdyno & and add memory to shared database (5MB I got for free), so that I can handle more number of concurrent users & handle more data storage smoothly.

Please share your experiences of deploying a production ready Java App on Heroku which is based on Play Framework (1.x)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have deployed your app to Heroku, you can add more dynos and increase your database allowance as you wish. Your application code should not be affected as to how big the database, or how many dynos you have running (as Play is a stateless architecture).

So, to answer your question...Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Test your deployment using [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to determine how many concurrent users can access your app before they are turned away or time out. If you are not happy with your numbers then try to [ramp up your dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling) until things look good.

Do note that you will need to pay for the service if you go over 750 dyno hours a month or use more than 5 MB of database storage. The database upgrade is an [add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql).